# New tabs UI still shows questions when searching for non-existent tag

Tags: bug, new-nav, tag-search

When you search for a non-existent tag in the new UI the page still displays all questions that were on the page before you searched until you change the sort order or if you navigate to the page itself

[image]

But when you navigate to the URL (or change the sort) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new you get the expected page

[image]

This is on Chrome Version 62.0.3202.89, and Firefox 56.0.2, and Microsoft Edge 40.15063.674.0, and IE Version 11.674.15063.0

Comment: Well the new navigation is on hold atm..read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/new-nav/info

Comment: @SurajRao That's fine, I don't expect it to be fixed anytime soon even if it wasn't on hold as it's a low priority bug, just simply reporting a bug for it.

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks, I wouldn't of known otherwise. Also thanks for adding in the extra tag :)